# filter pornography in a video/picture c# library

Tags: c#, .net, video-processing, imagefilter

How can you filter pornography in a video/picture?

Is there a library I can use? Commercial or open source is OK.

Comment: If you don't mind false positives, you could just paint a black rectangle over your image.

Comment: After long and hard look at multiple options. I have decided there is no magic bullet. You could use Amazon's Mechanical Turk to do the work if you got lot's of money. It is good engineering problem with business case. Come up with 95% solution -- most probably you can make enough money to retire. -- Thanks for all your input.

Answer (score 4):

For Video:

You would analyze the sound waves from the video. If there's lot of grunting and moans, find a way to recognize those patterns and label it as porn. However, you might get false tags for women's tennis match.

For Image:

Build a simulation model of a human brain which signals arousal from viewing erotic pictures. Some paramters would be excessive curves, and image recognition of the human anatomy. This is far more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not a real-time, you could use Amazon's Mechanical Turk to do the work. You'll have to pay the workforce, but it's a very cheap way to get menial jobs like this done.

Answer (score -1):

See, Porn Detection is not a very easy.

But there is surely a range of color that identifies the human skin. And you need to make a threshold of the color to identify the picture as porn. Say you take it as 70 %, so you go through all the pixel on the current screen and determine whether 70% of the pixels comes within the range of human skin color.

There is already few algorithm prepared for Face detection like :

> http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Face_Detection_processing.aspx

I hope this would help you to find a way on your point.

Comment: ..waiting for fat-people showing some extra surface-area to be labelled as porn with this algorithm

Comment: ..and wouldn't this be racial?